# Flights from Georgia to Crimea?

Tags: air-travel, georgia-country, crimea

What is the best option for traveling from Georgia to Crimea ?
I know it is difficult now to go to Crimea and the prices are too high. Which is the most optimal and cheapest option to get there?

Answer (score 3):

There are currently no international flights to Crimea due to European and US sanctions. Your only two choices are:

- Fly via Russia. Kayak shows flights for around $250 from Tbilisi to Simferopol
- Take a boat from Batumi to Sochi ($70). From Sochi take a flight to Simferopol ($75)

There are also potential options over land, but they're not cheaper.